# Child entity not deleting on removal of parent entity

Tags: java, jpa, orm

When deleting a parent entity I also want to remove the associated child entities (from the database). I have tried to make use of cascade on remove as seen below but I must be doing something incorrectly.

When calling remove on the parent entity object, I recieve the error message: "The entity is still referenced elsewhere in the database". I can confirm that the only place where the entity is referenced elsewhere in the database is in the two tables below (if I manually delete the child row from the database, the remove call on the parent works fine). I have been reading about entity objects and trying different things for the last 9 hours. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my parent table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TURTLE_LOOKUP")
public class TurtleLookup implements Serializable 
{

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "TURTLEID")
private int turtleid;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "TURTLE")
private String turtle;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "turtleType", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
List<TurtleReview> turtleReviews;

...
}
```

Here is my child table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TURTLE_REVIEW")
public class TurtleReview implements Serializable 
{

@Column(name = "TURTLE_REVIEW_ID")
private int turtleReviewId;

@Column(name = "TURTLE_YEAR")
private int turtleYear;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "TURTLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "TURTLEID")
private TurtleLookup turtleType;

@Column(name = "IS_COMPLETE")
private short isComplete;

...
}
```

EDIT/UPDATE:

If I change CascadeType.REMOVE to CascadeType.ALL, the TurtleReview entities are successfully deleted from the database when deleting the parent TurtleLookup entity object. However, when calling the below function to create a new TurtleReview entity object, JPA tries to insert a new TurtleLookup entity in to the database, which throws the exception: "Entry already resides within the DB. Transaction rolled back". Below is the code executed when creating a new TurtleReview entity.

```
public void setDatasetReviewComplete(TurtleLookup turtle, Short year, boolean isComplete)
{
TurtleReview turtleReview = getTurtleReview(turtle, year);
if (turtleReview == null)
{
turtleReview = new TurtleReview();
turtleReview.setTurtleYear(year)
turtleReview.setTurtleType(new a.b.entity.TurtleLookup(turtle.getId(), turtle.getValue()));
}
turtleReview.setIsComplete(isComplete ? (short)1 : 0);
entityManager.persist(turtleReview);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try change cascade value to all or all-delete-orphan

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "turtleType", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
List<TurtleReview> turtleReviews;

...
}
```

Comment: When I change both to CascadeType.ALL, the removal of child objects works, however, on creation of a new TurtleReview entry, I get the error message "Entry already resides within the DB". By debugging the SQL statement that the JPA/Entity framework is creating, I can see it is trying to insert a new row in the TURTLE_LOOKUP table when it should not be.

Comment: You should be removing the cascade on turtletype field    on TurtlleReview entity to avoid creating the turtlelookup while saving turtlereview object.

Answer (score 0):

Try with hibernate `@Cascade` annotation:

```
@Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL)
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "turtleReview") // mappedBy name of TurtleRewiew object field in TurtleLookup entity class
private TurtleLookup turtleType;
```

If your relationship is oneToOne you can't have oneToMany to the other side and you can't have `List<TurtleReview>`. If your relationship is oneToMany then your entities will be for example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TURTLE_LOOKUP")
public class TurtleLookup implements Serializable 
{

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "TURTLEID")
private int turtleid;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "TURTLE")
private String turtle;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "turtleType") // or add cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL and remove @Cascade if you are not using hibernate
@Cascade(value = CascadeType.ALL) 
List<TurtleReview> turtleReviews;

...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "TURTLE_REVIEW")
public class TurtleReview implements Serializable 
{

@Column(name = "TURTLE_REVIEW_ID")
private int turtleReviewId;

@Column(name = "TURTLE_YEAR")
private int turtleYear;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "TURTLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "TURTLEID")
private TurtleLookup turtleType;

@Column(name = "IS_COMPLETE")
private short isComplete;

...
}
```

Comment: I do not understand. Why can I not have OneToMany on the other side and Why can I not have List<TurtleReview>? The TurtleLookup can have many TurtleReviews but a TurtleReview can only have one TurtleLookup.

Comment: Yes you can have OneToMany and List<TurtleReview> on the TurtleLookup side, but then on the TurtleReview side  you must have ManyToOne (not oneToOne) - that means TurtleLookup can have many TurtleReviews and TurtleReview can have one TurtleLookup

Comment: Makes sense. I changed it and I still have the problem of JPA trying to create a new parent entity when creating a child entity.

Comment: Also, I cannot use @Cascade nor can I import it.

Comment: You can't import because you don't have dependeces for hibernate annotations. You use JPA, then you need `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "turtleType", cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.REMOVE)` and `@ManyToOne` to the other side

Comment: Yeah, this is what I am using.

Comment: If you use Hibernate's `Session` interface then you need to use Hibernate's annotation `@Cascade`. In your case only `cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL` will work because it covers all Hibernate operations as well, but `CascadeType.REMOVE` will work only if you use `EntityManager` not `Session`. To import Hibernate's `@Cascade` you need to add [dependences](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.9.Final) in your pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with your domain model, a part that is left out in the question. Do you possibly have circular cascades? If you have a circle of cascades and some of them are CascadeType.REMOVE and some are CascadeType.PERSIST, then Hibernate (not sure about other JPA implementation) will just do.... nothing when you call the remove() method. Without an error or exception message.